# Dynamic SQL: insert id not autoincrement

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

I want to copy some rows from a table to the same table. The `id` column of `TForms` table is not auto incremental but its `primary key`. How can I achieve that?

```
set @sourcetid = 17
set @newtbn = 15
set @template ='
INSERT INTO ' +@DB + '.[Tforms]
           (id
           ,[tablename])

     select id,
            @newtbn)
     from '+ @DB+ '.[Tforms] where tid=' +str(@sourcetid) 
exec sp_Executesql @template
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method would be to take the maximum id and add that to each current id:

```
insert into ' +@DB + '.[Tforms](id, [tablename])
     select (max_id + id) as id, @newtbn
     from (select t.*, max(id) over () as max_id
           from '+ @DB+ '.[Tforms] t
          ) t
     where tid = ' +str(@sourcetid) ;
```

Notes:

- Add `1` if the current id can be zero.  You can't use this method if `id`s can be negative.
- You should make the primary key `identity` or `newid()` so you don't have to manually set it.
- If you repeat this operation a lot, it could risk overflow under some circumstances.
- Don't pass the comparison in as a string.  Instead, use parameters (via `sp_executesql`).

EDIT:

A more general approach works regardless of minimum and maximum values:

```
insert into ' +@DB + '.[Tforms](id, [tablename])
     select max_id + row_number() over (order by id) as id, @newtbn
     from (select t.*, max(id) over () as max_id
           from '+ @DB+ '.[Tforms] t
          ) t
     where tid = ' +str(@sourcetid) ;
```

Comment: this method inserts the first id as the maximum of the existing. But it should insert the maximum+1

Comment: @alxem . . . There was a typo.  The `as` should have been `+`.

Comment: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: is it possible to make the primary key identity with auto increment without affecting the existing values?

Comment: @alxem . . . The only subquery in this query is in the `from` clause.  It is allowed to return more than one value.  As for your other comment, new questions should be asked as a question and not in a comment.